# Azure Cloud Shell opening to a black screen

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

[image]

As soon as I login to Azure Cloud Shell, it is redirecting me to a black screen as it is unable to load bootstrap and jQuery.

Is there any fix for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any extension installed that can block content? Please try it with another browser. It works e. g. in a clean chrome.

Comment: Do you have the storage in Azure with your account that you log in?

Comment: @MartinBrandl I do not have any extensions that can block the content. As per my observations, it occurs every time I switch the between company and personal networks.

Comment: Yes @CharlesXu. I do have the storage in my Azure account.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Martin (could be plug-in/browser related) and Charles (right account) suggestion's. 
There was some issue identified between approximately 13:45 and 14:59 UTC on 16 Oct 2019, a subset of customers may have experienced latency issues with the Azure Portal, Command Line and Azure PowerShell. This is issue has been mitigated. 
Please checkout -https://status.azure.com/status/history/ for more details on this. If there is any issue kindly let us know for further investigation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have faced this problem on multiple occasions when I delete the cache of the browser and connect to corporate network. The problem disappears as soon as I switch to a personal network.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises because you have not mounted any storage to the azure environment.
just go to shell.azure.com and then mount the storage by choosing your subscription. And when its done close the current tab and reload your azure site. Now the shell will run again.
hope this solution helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Logging in from a Chrome incognito window worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance you are on a trial account

[image]

1. Then go to your https://portal.azure.com/
2. then on side menu
   `Subscriptions` and pick your subscription
3. then again on the newly opened side menu
   `Resource providers`
4. there should be hundreds of them in the search type in
   **CloudS**
   [image]
5. Then if `Microsoft.CloudShell` is `NotRegistered` click on the menu
   `Register`
   [image]
6. Then wait till it is registered and try clearing the cookies and re-logging into https://portal.azure.com/